# Remember-me- spring security

Tags: spring-security, remember-me

I am currently trying to implement remember me functionality in my website. Following is part of my configuration

```
<security:remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" />  
<bean id="rememberMeServices" class="com.entertainment.ecom.web.auth.EcomRemembe rMeServices">  
<property name="userDetailsService" ref="ecomUserDetailsService"/>  
<property name="key" value="a23eef6dfd1514cb885f47070380ff18"/>  
<property name="cookieName" value="ENTC"/>  
<property name="tokenValiditySeconds" value="80000"/>  
</bean>
```

My `EcomRememberMeServices` extends `AbstractRememberMeServices` & I have overridden `onLoginFail` & `onLoginSuccess` methods. My question is, from where my `onLoginSuccess()` method will be called?

I have tried to run above configuration & it was seen that `onLoginFail` gets called through `RememberMeAuthenticationFilter(rememberMeServices.loginFail(request, response))` but when I checked source code for this filter, I could not find any call for `onLoginSuccess()` or `loginSuccess()` method. So do I need to call this explicitly?

In `BasicAuthenticationFilter`, there is a call for this method. So I tried to use it but still i does not work.(`<http-basic/>`). So can anyone please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

There is one more method logout(), which is called by logout filter. I guess you have to inject `rememberMeServices` into Login and Logout Filter as well (I am not sure if it can be done within http element in xml):

```
    <bean id="logoutFilter"   class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" type="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler" ref="logoutSuccessHandler" />
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <list value-type="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler">
            <ref local="rememberMeServices"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

and

```
<bean id="formLoginFilter"   class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
     ...

     <property name="rememberMeServices">
            <ref local="rememberMeServices" />
     </property> 
</bean>
```